# Load and .html (wall posts) to different pages (so I can have wall posts in all the pages i want to add them) ,using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm started with  angular yesterday and I want to have an .html with some behaviour in a separate file and add it to other ones. For instance and I want to have the wall posts in one .html, and I want to be able to add that wall posts to any page I want in a particular tag. I used a little of jquery.. So what I have done is this (but the digest doesn't seem to be working or something):

This is the  html I want to add (I test it alone and it works):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
     <b> {{ x.texto }}</b> {{x.id }}
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" ng-model="tbPost">
<button ng-click="publicarPost()">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<script>


function customersController($scope,$http) {

     $http.post(urlSitio + url , {id_partido : 1}).
        success(
           function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.names = data.consulta;
           $scope.$digest();
        }).
        error(errorCallback);

}


</script>
```

this is how I add it to a a tag in other page

```
// the function that load the .html
function cargarControl(url,tag){
   $.get(urlControl+url, {},
        function(content) {
            $("#"+tag).append(content);
        }, 'html');
}
// calling that function
cargarControl("wallPartido", "divPosts");
angular.element('customersController').scope().$digest();
```

And it doesnt work, the page  shows  {{ x.texto}} {{x.id}} instead of the posts...
I also tried $digest(); but doesnt work either.  How can I make it work? If this can't be done in this way, is there another one? (Actually I would like one without jquery)

EDIT: What I want to achieve is having one html file with some behaviour (like a control in .net) and be able to embed it to a particular tag in any other page I want. For instance if I have a page that brings all the wall posts, i want be able to easily embed it  to some tag in other pages. Think that you build a javascript calculator, and you don't want paste de code, but you want to call the .html that contains it to add it in other pages.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Please provide more details.

Comment: You want a certain element that you can add to any page?

Comment: yes!!! I already tried to explain better in the new edit. I think my english is kind of poor... sorry

Comment: and i can do it, but angular doesn't work when I embed it

Comment: You should look in to custom directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example: http://jsbin.com/xehovigabule/1/watch?html,js,output

I created a custom directive which you are able to add to any page.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('customersController', customersController);

function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $scope.wallposts = [{
    texto: "Lorem ipsum"
  },{
    texto: "Dolor sit maet"
  }, {
    texto: "Lorem sorem"
  }];

 $http.post("http://get.data")
 .success(function(data) {
       $scope.names = data.consulta;
 })
 .error(function() {
   //err
 });
}

angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("wallPosts", wallPosts);

function wallPosts() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "path/to/partial.html",
    scope: {
        posts: '='
    }
};
}
```